# How to declare an array of an object statically

Tags: c#, arrays, object, static

I'm a long time C programmer but new to C#. I want to declare an object then creating an array of that object filling it statically (I have a very large table to enter). For example

```
class MyObject {
    int i1;
    string s1;
    double d1;
};

static MyObject[] myO = new MyObject {{1,"1",1.0}, {2,"2",2.0}};
```

This doesn't work but you get the idea. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Here's the link to [Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you have public fields/properties on your class:

```
class MyObject
{
    public int i1 { get; set; }
    public string s1 { get; set; }
    public double d1 { get; set; }
}   // note: no semicolon needed here

static MyObject[] myO = { new MyObject { i1 = 1, s1 = "1", d1 = 1.0 },
                          new MyObject { i1 = 2, s1 = "2", d1 = 2.0 },
                        };
```

Comment: thanks this did it. It's a lot more test (cut and paste) than C, but I get it.

Comment: what if myobject has itnernally another array of objects?

Answer (score 3):

You need to fill the array with object instances.

Create a constructor that takes parameters, then write

```
new MyObject[] { new MyObject(a, b, c), new MyObject(d, e, f) }
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to initialize the array with new object instances.

```
class MyObject 
{
    int i1;
    string s1;
    double d1;

    public MyObject(int i, string s, double d)
    {
        i1 = i;
        s1 = s;
        d1 = d;
    }
};

static MyObject[] myO = new MyObject[] { 
    new MyObject(1, "1", 1.0), 
    new MyObject(2, "2", 2.0)
};
```

Unfortunately there is no way to specify custom initializers like they are for arrays of built-in types or dictionaries. For (future) reference of what I mean:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var list = new List<string> { "abc", "def" };
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "abc", 1 }, { "def", 2 } };
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to instantiate the objects in the array:

```
static MyObject[] myO = new MyObject
{
   new MyObject { i1 = 1, s1 = "1", d1 = 1.0 },
   new MyObject { i1 = 2, s1 = "2", d1 = 2.0 },
};
```

Comment: MyObject has 3 private fields so this won't work unless you do somthing

Comment: Good point; in this case he'll either need to expose the properties with setters or add a constructor which takes those values.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things wrong here. Firstly all your variables are private. Secondly you are not calling a constructor.

```
    class MyObject
    {
        public MyObject(int i1, string s1, double d1)
        {
            this.i1 = i1;
            this.s1 = s1;
            this.d1 = d1;
        }

        int i1;
        string s1;
        double d1;
    };

    static MyObject[] objects = new MyObject[] { new MyObject(1, "2", 3), new MyObject(1, "2", 3) };
```

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly what you want but you can achieve your goal with following code:

```
class MyObject
{
    public int i1;
    public string s1;
    public double d1;
};

static MyObject[] myO = new[]  { new MyObject { i1=1, s1="1", d1=1.0 }, new MyObject { i1=2, s1="2", d1=2.0 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class Foo
{
  public static Widget[] Widgets { get ; private set ; }
  static Foo()
  {
    Widgets = new Widget[]{ new Widget(1) , new Widget(2) , ... } ;
  }
}
```